# Windows XP Embedded install .NET3.0

Tags: windows, embedded

I'm getting crazy with this problem. I got in my hands a Windows XP embedded and I need to install Framework .NET3.0 and I tried everything in my mind. I've been reading a lot of wXPe and everybody says that you have to take the XPe Rollout 1.0 from your tools and remake the image.

This is my biggest problem, I didn't have any of this tools, I just have a computer with wXPe installed and I need to install my software and I don't have any kind of feedback of who have done it.

I spend a lot of time to understand the ewf and finally I get disabled. But now, I need .NET3.0 and once I get unpacked I can continue with the installation, it seems freezed, I can't continue with the installation.

I've tried to install .NET2.0, it unpacks but suddently stops.

Any idea?! I'm start thinking that is impossible without rebulding the image, but at this time, this is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any particular expertise in the subject, however [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255(v=winembedded.5).aspx#ComponentsRequiredforNETFramework30Installation) seems relevant. Have you had the opportunity to look at it? If so, which parts of that article are not working? Generally for embedded device development you are going to need to full toolset.

Comment: Yes I've checked this article, but the problem is that I don't have any of this tools, I just have the administrator password of the machine, and I "just" need to install .NET3.0 to get my software work. And I won't have any kind of help of the people who done this embedded. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get .Net framework installed on your XP Embedded image?
The problem with XP embedded is, if you leave one component out while building your image then some features/programs won't work or install.

I had the same problem with one of my XP embedded images and I figured out that I had to add the .Net framework 2 component in order to install .Net framework 3 on the image. A website I find handy is [this one](http://www.seanliming.com/WES2009_XPe.html), there's sld's on the website you can use, if you don't have the platform builder, I will be able to help you to build a new image